# changing Farm Admin from Local user to Domain user

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, administration, farm-admin

I just encountered a SharePoint Foundation farm where it is installed by using Local admin account.
The whole farm and its SharePoint service are running either by Local service, Local system or specifically by that local admin account.

Now I need to change with a dedicated domain account, say SharePoint Admin account.

As it is a production server I little hesitating to change it.

Can any one suggest where all I need to make change this service account !! and is there any risk in changing at any place !!

Comment: You can add service accounts in Central administration and manage accounts for services and app pools from Central Administration. You can get manage service accounts link under Security tab.

Comment: I tried to change the service account in Central Administration but it is not picking up the domain account...

Comment: Have you added your sharepoint machine in the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a risk , and it will require outage , so it's heavily recommended to try this in your test environment before implementing in your Production environment.

Meanwhile, you will need to change the following services accounts to the new farm account

1. Farm account in Service account
2. Service Application Pool - Security Token app pool service account.
3. Service Application Pool – Sharepoint Web application app pool service account.
4. Windows Service – Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service (if you already start it)
5. Windows Service – User Profile Synchronization Service (if you already configure it)

To do this , apply the following steps :

- Create a new domain user.
- In SQL server , Provide this user a `dbcreator` server role, and the SQL Server `securityadmin` server role.
- Add the new domain user to `Managed Account` in Central Administration > Security > General Security > Configure managed accounts

[image]

- Go to Security –> Configure Service Accounts.

[image]

- Select Central administration and set the new domain farm account.
- repeat the previous step for web application app pool and Security Token app pool.
- Run the following command to update farm credentials

> stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin "[DOMAIN\USERNAME]"
>   –password "[PASSWORD]"

- In Local users and groups, Add the new farm account for this following groups in

  - WSS_WPG
  - WSS_ADMIN_WPG
- Perform `iisreset`

**Note :**

For more steps check

- [CHANGING THE SHAREPOINT FARM ACCOUNT (FROM A NON-DOMAIN TO A DOMAIN ACCOUNT)](https://theblobfarm.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/changing-the-sharepoint-farm-account-from-a-non-domain-to-a-domain-account/)
- [How to change SharePoint 2013 application pool account.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/denotation/2014/02/27/how-to-change-sharepoint-2013-application-pool-account/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, but When I am trying to change Service Accounts. SharePoint is not taking any other account, mean it is not recognising Domain Account !

Comment: you are welcome by bro , this because any service account should be domain user and added to managed account , so add it in Security > General Security > Configure managed accounts > add the service account  , please don't hesitate to tell me if you need any calarafication :)